# Unable to boot Windows 10 from any device

Tags: windows-10, boot

I was normally using windows 10 as i do every day, when it got stuck on some heavy operations. I thought it was normal as my computer hardware is quite slow. After waiting i decided to force reboot it.

At this point i was unable to boot back in Windows. After showing the windows logo it started doing some weird attempt to recovery which always led to a black screen.
The same screen showed up when trying to get into safe mode.

I booted my Ubuntu and created a bootable Windows 10 USB to try to recover the disk.
When i booted the USB the windows logo showed up, and then we are back to a black screen. (Without the recovery attempt).
I also tried to create the bootable usb from an another Windows computer using both rufus and the Windows Media Creation Tool. Neither of them worked.

What am i missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: are you sure it booted from the usb drive ?? Could have been that it was booting from the HDD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to try if you haven't already:

- Ensure all external devices and peripherals like USB, external HDD,
  printers etc are unplugged (except for keyboard/mouse) and then
  restart.
- When you're at the black screen try CTRL + ALT + DEL. If this wakes
  the PC, it should be on a screen where there are power options on the
  bottom right. Click restart (or hold shift then click restart for
  boot into safe mode).
- An alternative to this is holding Win key + CTRL + Shift + B to
  attempt to restart display drivers. If successful there's meant to be
  a beep which at least shows Windows is responsive.
- If you haven't already try powering down the PC by holding the power 
  button in for 5-10 seconds. Or alternatively powering it off then
  unplugging it from the mains power for a minute then powering back
  on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem turned out to be the ssd where i had windows installed, it had many damaged sectors. I still don't understand why having it plugged in while booting windows from the usb was preventing the usb with windows from booting.